# Pass ontouchlistener to parent

Tags: android

I have 4 buttons in my activity and each of these buttons have a `onTouchListener`. I want to pass that event to the button's parent which is a Linear Layout. To achieve that, I have used 
THIS :

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            onTouchEvent(ev);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can I ask you why you wanted to do this ?

Comment: ""Can I ask you why?""  Well, if you remember, You answered my previous question about screen coordinates. Now, I am succesfull in getting them so I don't want them from the buttons. I want them only from the parent(Linear Layout).

Comment: if you don't want it for buttons then add it to the parent layout

Comment: Yes but then the area of the parent layout which the button takes is no longer touchable.

Comment: Why do you use `Button`s if you don't want them to be clickable !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OnTouchListener documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) indicates that `onTouch()` returns

> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

So since you return `true`, you indicate that the touch listener of your button consumed the event, and the even doesn't get propagated any further.
Returning `false` instead will make the event be propagated further up the view hierarchy.

Note though, that a button which unconditionally doesn't listen to touch events isn't a button. I would make sure whether a `TextView` for example isn't enough.

---

Although this would be true and sufficient for a simple `TextView` (or any `View` for that matter), you should note that `Button` is a clickable view and by default behaves as such. This means that whatever you return as a result of `onTouch()`, the touch event won't be propagated further and the `Button`'s `onClick()` method will be called.

To disable this behavior and have it behave as you expect, just make it non-clickable:

```
button.setClickable(false);
```

Again, using a button doesn't make much sense anymore though.

Comment: I changed `return true` in onTouch to `return false` but still the same results

Comment: Please define what you actually mean by "same result" and "doesn't work". Meaning, how do you check it ? The problem may be independent of the buttons. Try making them invisible (`button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`) and make sure that this "works" first.

Comment: Yes it works after making them invisible! You are right. I'll be using textViews now. thanks a lot for your help and sorry for the dumb question

Comment: No problem, no dumb question. I edited my answer to explain the behavior. But if you don't need them to be clickable a `TextView` is actually the best way to go.

Comment: Actually I just realized that I need to make them clickable. I used your suggestion of using textViews but they behave the same after making them clickable like buttons! Please help!

Comment: A clickable `View` (whether a `TextView` or a `Button` or anything else) will consume touch events to account for the click action so they don't get propagated. That you need the button to be clickable and the parent to receive touch events looks like a design smell. Maybe open another question to get help finding a suitable design for your use case. Technically speaking, you could make just the parent clickable, or you could make the text view non-clickable and handle a click-like behavior yourself in its touch event handler then returning `false` (but brace yourself for problems).